# Code structure for sending a lot of values in C

Tags: c, structure, protocols, uart

I'm making a robot that should have simple two way communication for a large variety of values to a desktop via UART (serial communication, modem port). It's also desirable for it to be easy to add new values.

The board on the robot is an Olimexino, a rather powerful Arduino clone with an arm processor. For the sake of simplicity, I believe it could be affordable to store all relevant global values as floats.

My idea is to store all values in a matrix, like below. On the robot I for instance would like multiple controllers, which here can be viewed just as a heap of values grouped. These should be easy to modify and send.

```
  enum rows
  {
     controller_a, 
     controller_b,
     controller_c,
     rows
  }

  enum controllers
  {
     controller_value1,
     controller_value2,
     columns
  }

  float values[rows][columns]
```

This should make it quite easy to for instance add a controller. It would also be rather easy to send and insert values, as I could target any vale by just sending the coordinates as [row, column].

The question is though, are there other better ways?

Should I perhaps define the controllers in structs instead

```
  struct controller
  {
      float controller_value1;
      etc

  }controllers[columns];
```

If I make sure that all controllervalues are floats, maybe I could use pointers to the structs for easy read/write? I dont't know how to do that pointer aritmethics though. I guess it would require a specific routine for handling each different struct, meaning that the code wouldnt be that easy to modify?

Comment: What's your consideration? If you can afford a bit of bloat for the payload (not much anyway), I suggest to draft an extensible protocol so that you won't mess up when adding new controller and have different incompatible versions of computer and robot. A simple list of key-value pairs of {count, {controller-id, value}...} with a prefix header of {version,command="set-values"} would be good start.

Comment: What would "count" be here?

Comment: @user3050215 - The number of {controller-id, value} pairs perhaps?

Comment: Why not use a json object.

Comment: perhaps json is an overkill for little robot's mcu and memory constraints.

Comment: Why was this put on hold, I do not see why it is too broad? I think the user had a specific problem regarding comparing different data formats. Perhaps this should be migrated to programmers instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is a very very bad idea to use floats if you are going to be sending the data between devices, particularly if they are going to be of different architectures, it would be far more sound to use 64 bit integers and implement a fixed point by hand where necessary. Floats are not of a predictable format in memory and thus trying to serialise them is highly difficult.

Second, I think you have some sound ideas as far as storing the data goes, using a 2D array of a fixed type to store the data will work well and hopefully be well optimised. The enums are also a nice way of avoiding confusion. However what you are missing is a way to send them easily. As you are using a micro a nice simple protocol would do, may I suggest something along the lines of the following. This assumes you are keeping the table synced between your computer and the arduino like:

```
uint64_t ValueTable[CONTROLLER_MAX][VALUE_MAX];
uint32_t UartFD; // This gets set somewhere during init
// It should be a non blocking fd so we dont block if there are
// no value changes

void SetValue(uint32_t ControllerNum, uint32_t ValueIndex, uint64_t Value)
{
    ValueTable[ControllerNum][ValueIndex] = Value;
    write(UartFD, &ControllerNum, sizeof(uint32_t));
    write(UartFD, &ValueIndex, sizeof(uint32_t));
    write(UartFD, &Value, sizeof(uint64_t));
}

void GetValue(void)]
{
    uint32_t ContNum;
    uint32_t ValIndx;
    uint64_t Value;
    if(!read(UartFD, &ContNum, sizeof(uint32_t)))
    {
        // No data waiting
        return;
    }
    // Wait for the rest
    while(!read(UartFD, &ValIndx, sizeof(uint32_t)));
    while(!read(UartFD, &Value, sizeof(uint64_t)));
    ValueTable[ContNum][ValIndx] = Value;
}
```

Obviously this is the version for the PC, the arduino needs read and write replaced with Serial.read and Serial.write and does not need the first argument, otherwise the two are the same.Obviously you need to call those wherever you write to a value in the table.

Effectively for what you are doing your idea is great, just make sure to keep the implementation fast and simple so it runs well on the robot's embedded system. Yuo need not worry too much about extensibility, as you are likely to update both at once, particularly if you can keep a fair amount of common code between the PC and robot.

Comment: Just to mention, I have worked on this kind of system many times before so if you have any other questions on it or my answer is not clear please comment.

Comment: That looks like a minimalistic and nice protocol! 

Just now I tried to implement some sort of functionality for sending structs. It's just becoming painful and hardcoded as all structs are so different. 

However, I would like it if I could use structs as regularly in the program. 

I'm thinking about storing pointers to interesting values in the structs in a sort of send matrix like above, and use that. The matrix would then glue the structs and the UART together in a way. 


What about that?

Comment: @user3050215 I should probably not recommend this, but if you are willing to be careful you can indeed send struts. You really have two options, the first is to see if your compiler supports struct packing, which will put the data into a relatively portable, byte aligned format suitable for transmission, however it does significantly slow down the code as it causes unaligned reads to happen. The second and easier way is during initialization send an array of offsets to the parts of the struct, eg: offset = &(myStr->propertyFoo) - myStr; that number can then be used after sending it all.

Comment: @user3050215 However if I understand your meaning, storing the data in structs, then pointers in the big array, that will indeed work and should be more efficient than the methods mentioned above. Make sure that you keep all of the data to a single data type however and avoid floating point as said before.